# Sums in the same table with linq lambda expression

Tags: linq

I am new to using LINQ lambda expressions and I have to make a query in a table called stock and it has as attributes (id, prodId, prodCode, Quantity, StockInternalStatus, location), StockInternalStatus can be available or not available, what I want do is get a single list with the total quantity and the total available quantity of each product, that means, if I have for example the following stock:

```
Stock1: prodCode = A; Qty = 1; StockInternalStatus = Available; Location = sd1
Stock2: prodCode = A; Qty = 2; StockInternalStatus = Not Available; Location = sd2
Stock3: prodCode = B; Qty = 2; StockInternalStatus = Available; Location = sd3
Stock4: prodCode = B; Qty = 2; StockInternalStatus = Available; Location = sd4
```

the result should be:

```
prodCode = A; TotalQuantity = 3; QtyAvailable = 1

prodCode = A; TotalQuantity = 4; QtyAvailable = 4
```

Can someone help me please? I have been punching code for 3 days and doing tests and it does not work. this is the code that I made:

```
Context.Stocks.Where(e=>e.IsActive /*&& ( e.ProductCode=="63149")*/)
.GroupBy(s=>s.ProductCode)
.SelectMany(gr=>gr.Select(st=>new
{
             TotalQuantity = gr.Sum(c=>c.Quantity),

             Count = gr.Count(),
             Pr= st.ProductCode,
             PrId = st.ProductId,
             StockInternalStatus = st.StockInternalStatus   
}))
//.Distinct()
.GroupJoin
(Context.Stocks.Where(p=>p.StockInternalStatus=="Available" && p.IsActive)
, ss => ss.PrId, sss => sss.ProductId, 
(ss,sss) => new { TotalQuantity = ss.TotalQuantity, ProductCode = ss.Pr,
QtyAvailable = sss.Sum(a=>a.Quantity)
})
.Distinct()
.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

and if I specify a product code it gives me the result for that product but if i want to obtain the result of all the products I get the following error:

> **Error: The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter
>   or the query must use a nullable type**.

According to what I understand this error is that there are products from the first consultation that when the GroupJoin is made with the second does not come out because they are not available as I only take out those that are available in the second, which interests me to take the total available but I'm not sure I understand it well.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is `PrId` in your sample code that is not in your sample table? What is the `GroupJoin` attempting to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `projections` to select and format multiple sorts of data from you list (`TotalQuantity` and `QtyAvailable`). Here is a working example for your issue :

```
var products = Context.Stocks.GroupBy(s => s.ProdCode)
                             .Select(s => new
                             {
                                 ProdCode = s.Key,
                                 TotalQuantity = s.Sum(o => o.Qty),
                                 QtyAvailable = s.Where(o => o.StockInternalStatus == "Available").Sum(o => o.Qty)
                             });
```